# How do you create a sitemap index in Django?

Tags: python, django, sitemap

The Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index) is very minimal and I can't seem to get this to work.

Currently I have 3 individual sitemaps, and I would like to create a sitemap index for them:

```
(r'^sitemap1\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps':sitemap1}),
(r'^sitemap2\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps':sitemap2}),
(r'^sitemap3\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps':sitemap3}),
```

The Django documentation mentions adding something along the lines of:

```
url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', views.sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
```

What is "section" in this case? And how do I access this index file? Is it downloadable or is it accessible via a url?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**
Basically I would like to accomplish this in Django: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712

Answer (score 1):

If you included the app with a namespace (e.g. *include('myapp.urls', namespace='myapp'*), then you need to include the namespace when reversing, e.g. *{% url 'myapp:my_url_name' %}* or *reverse('myapp:my_url_name')*.

```
url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', cache_page(86400)(views.sitemap), {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='sitemapsname'),
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', cache_page(86400)(views.index), {'sitemaps': sitemaps, 'sitemap_url_name': 'posts:sitemapsname'}),
```

note: **posts**:sitemapsname is my app

see source code of Django: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py

Answer (score 0):

The "sections" are what you define in a dictionary, something like this:

**urls.py**

```
from .views import StaticSitemap, BlogSitemap, NewsSitemap

SITEMAPS = {
    'blog': BlogSitemap,
    'main': StaticSitemap,
    'news': NewsSitemap,
}
```

These will show up as **sitemap-blog.xml**, **sitemap-main.xml** and **sitemap-news.xml** in your **sitemap.xml** index.

These are laid out in your **views.py**, for example:

```
class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "never"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return BlogPage.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.date

    def location(self, obj):
        return obj.url
```

You don't need to access the index file, as there is a default in Django that will be used. It should just work automatically.