# extends: conditional templates in django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to have a conditional extends? Like I have is:

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load custom_tags %}
{% load static %}
```

but I want the template main/base to be conditional like:

```
{% if request.path == '/page/lawyer/' %}
    {% extends "base_lawyer.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This is not possible in Django, `extends` must be on the first line, you will have to use `import` instead

Comment: @gogaz exactly, how do I use import instead?

Comment: That did not work either :(

Comment: Why not just keep this logic in the view and pass on a context variable, extended say, which is equal to 'base_lawyers.html' when the request path is /page/lawyer/ and equal to 'base.html' otherwise. Then you can just put {% extends enteded %}.

Comment: @DisneylandSC I cannot do that in views.py since it is being created automatically in sitemap like the Blog here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947135/how-do-you-create-a-sitemap-index-in-django